# Continuity of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}\to S^n$, $x\to \frac{x}{|x|}$.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I want to show the map $q:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\to S^n$, $x\to \frac{x}{|x|}$ is continuous. Here $S^n$ is the $n$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. I have tried the following and would really appreciate if someone can help me correct it.

$f:X\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous if and only if $\pi_i\circ f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ are all continuous (by the characteristic property of product spaces) and $f,g:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous implies $f\pm g, f.g,\tfrac{f}{g}$ are all continuous (provided $g$ does not vanish on $X$).

The identity map and $x_i\mapsto |x_i|$ are continuous. Hence, $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous. Now, using the subspace property ($f:X\to Y$ is continuous implies $f:X\to f(X)$ is continuous), by nature of $q$ normalizing $x$, $q$ is continuous.

In quite some books I have used, details like this are not explicitly given. I understand that the purpose is it allow the reader work out the details and eventually be able to judge by intuition whether such functions are continuous or not. With this question, I want to get all the details right, so that I can develop the required geometric intuition.

If there is any other GENERAL method to show continuity, I would greatly appreciate that too.

Comment: It is correct, except for a detail: the map $x_i\mapsto|x_i|$ makes no sense. What you should have mentioned was the map $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n+1})\mapsto x_i$ (and also the fact that this is not *one* map but $n+1$ maps).

Comment: A map is continuous if an only if the preimage of any open subset is open. If $U \subset S^n$ is open, then $q^{-1}(U)$ is the cone generated by $U$ with apex $\{0\}$ (i.e the set $\{tp | t > 0, p \in U\}$. Can you show that it is open in $\Bbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, I should have been mindful about that indeed!!

Comment: @Didier Thanks for the suggestion!! I had to also show that this map $q$ is a quotient map and while doing that I figured out about the fibers whose union gives the cone you mention. I argued that each point in the cone has an open ball contained fully in the cone.

Comment: @Didier Why are we excluding $t<0$?

Comment: @frelg $q(x) = p \in U \iff x = tp$ with $t = |x| > 0$.

Comment: Perhaps I missed it, but the crucial ingredient is that the function $\phi(x)=\|x\|$ (I want no confusion with absolute value) is continuous on $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, forgot about the norm property 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $x \mapsto x/|x|$ is continuous as a map $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, by considering each coordinate and using usual properties of continuous functions. But it also factors through the inclusion $S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so is a continuous map with the subspace topology on the target.

Comment: I feel this is more useful for any problem of this type. Thinking of the subspace rather than the product topology. Thank you!

Comment: I think it's good to know what tools are available in general. Because of their respective universal properties, it is usually more straightforward to show that maps into a subspace or product topology are continuous, similarly for maps out of a quotient topology.

Comment: Also "considering each coordinate" *is* using the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: That's some valuable information :)